# What form of JavaScript is this?

Tags: javascript, userscripts

I like games and found a JavaScript Code that adds GUI into the game and draws objects, I'm curious about modifying this code This really intrigues me and I'm curious if it modifies Game data This is a JavaScript user script for the game https://Krunker.io, PS I have had to remove a large section of this code to be able to submit this. Can somebody identify the type of JavaScript being used in this code, please?

```
const _0x2fef=['\x27\x20value=\x27','tablinks','</span><div\x20class=\x27slidecontainer\x27><input\x20type=\x27range\x27\x20min=\x27','2EocMfR','round','getElementById','ctx','some','banner','arrayTest','Banned','Smooth\x20Assist\x20&\x20Aim\x20Correction','canThrow','http://0n-2000s.radionetz.de/0n-2000s.aac','Rup22iG','scale','keydown','createObserver','checkbox','MIA','scope','random','select','slideTimer','setAttribute','protocol','console','Aim\x20through\x20Penetratables','stack','objectHas','http://1a-classicrock.radionetz.de/1a-classicrock.mp3','instructionsUpdate','aimVal','yDirChase','lineTo','containsPoint','setItem','rate','isType','games','button','json','isMod','smoothCamAssist','renderTarget','\x27,\x20this.value)(_0x4c0d19,_0x4ccccc,_0x35356b,_0x2569a5){return Math['atan2'](_0x4ccccc-_0x2569a5,_0x4c0d19-_0x35356b);}[_0x52fa83(0x1bf)](_0x3fb0f,_0x3ed26d,_0x3bd33e,_0x3f915e){const _0x435f70=_0x52fa83;return Math[_0x435f70(0x312)]((_0x3bd33e-=_0x3fb0f)*_0x3bd33e+(_0x3f915e-=_0x3ed26d)*_0x3f915e);}[_0x52fa83(0x26c)](_0x2150ea,_0x49536d){const _0x56c6d7=_0x52fa83;return Math['atan2'](Math[_0x56c6d7(0x1d5)](_0x49536d-_0x2150ea),Math['cos'](_0x2150ea-_0x49536d));}['containsPoint'](_0xdadfcf){const _0x328668=_0x52fa83;let _0x47e04f=this[_0x328668(0x36a)][_0x328668(0x35c)][_0x328668(0x1e1)];for(let _0x41642d=0x0;_0x41642d<0x6;_0x41642d++){if(_0x47e04f[_0x41642d][_0x328668(0x355)](_0xdadfcf)<0x0)return![];}return!![];}[_0x52fa83(0x293)](_0x4c63f7,_0x5ca879,_0x33e554,_0x350df1=0x0){const _0x464553=_0x52fa83;return _0x4c63f7['y']+=_0x350df1,_0x4c63f7[_0x464553(0x263)](this[_0x464553(0x36a)]['camera']),_0x4c63f7['x']=(_0x4c63f7['x']+0x1)/0x2,_0x4c63f7['y']=(-_0x4c63f7['y']+0x1)/0x2,_0x4c63f7['x']*=_0x5ca879,_0x4c63f7['y']*=_0x33e554,_0x4c63f7;}}function _0x1d15(_0x49e259,_0x39832a){return _0x1d15=function(_0x4aa4d6,_0x5854dc){_0x4aa4d6=_0x4aa4d6-0x1b7;let _0x44585c=_0x2fef[_0x4aa4d6];return _0x44585c;},_0x1d15(_0x49e259,_0x39832a);}const log=console[_0x52fa83(0x352)][_0x52fa83(0x208)](null,_0x52fa83(0x372)),main=new Main();
```

Comment: It's been obfuscated. It's not any "type" of JavaScript, it's just been obfuscated to prevent you from reading it.

Answer (score 1):

This is some [obfuscated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_(software)) javascript code to protect it from re-using it. Probably with [obfuscator.io](https://obfuscator.io/)

Answer (score 0):

well first off there are some key giveaways that the \x00 strings are some type of hex value, try to convert it and find out? it looks heavily obfuscated, only see this type of code when people don't want others to poke around.